# XSLT transformation of incompleteXML data into table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have following XML file

```html
<root>
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <id>1</id>
      <title>entry A</title>
      <group>1</group>
      <category>a</category>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <id>2</id>
      <title>entry B</title>
      <group>1</group>
      <category>c</category>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <id>3</id>
      <title>entry C</title>
      <group>2</group>
      <category>b</category>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <id>4</id>
      <title>entry D</title>
      <group>2</group>
      <category>c</category>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <id>5</id>
      <title>entry E</title>
      <group>3</group>
      <category>a</category>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <id>6</id>
      <title>entry F</title>
      <group>4</group>
      <category>c</category>
    </entry>
  </entries>
  <groups>
    <group id="1">
      <title>Group 1</title>
    </group>
    <group id="2">
      <title>Group 2</title>
    </group>
    <group id="3">
      <title>Group 3</title>
    </group>
    <group id="4">
      <title>Group 4</title>
    </group>
  </groups>
  <categories>
    <category id="a">
      <title>A</title>
    </category>
    <category id="b">
      <title>B</title>
    </category>
    <category id="c">
      <title>C</title>
    </category>
  </categories>
</root>
```

which contains table definition (groups node corresponds to rows and category node corresponds to columns) and table entries. Each entry is identified by group and column id, and entries defined not for all cells.

I need as output a table, like this one:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Groups</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <!-- category name -->
      <th>B</th>
      <!-- category name -->
      <th>C</th>
      <!-- category name -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th group-id="1">Group 1</th>
      <!-- group name -->
      <th group-id="1" category-id="a"><span>entry A</span></th>
      <th group-id="1" category-id="b"></th>
      <th group-id="1" category-id="c"><span>entry B</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th group-id="3">Group 2</th>
      <!-- group name -->
      <th group-id="2" category-id="a"></th>
      <th group-id="2" category-id="b"><span>entry C</span></th>
      <th group-id="2" category-id="c"><span>entry D</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th group-id="3">Group 3</th>
      <!-- group name -->
      <th group-id="3" category-id="a"><span>entry E</span></th>
      <th group-id="3" category-id="b"></th>
      <th group-id="3" category-id="c"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th group-id="4">Group 4</th>
      <!-- group name -->
      <th group-id="4" category-id="a"></th>
      <th group-id="4" category-id="b"></th>
      <th group-id="4" category-id="c"><span>entry F</span></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

which would fill up all the cells of the table with empty spans, if there are no data in initial xml.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Well, for your rows you want e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="//entry" group-by="group"><tr>...</tr></xsl:for-each-group>` and the contents of each `tr` you populate from your known `<xsl:variable name="columns" select="//categories/category/@id"/>` either with `<xsl:for-each select="$columnes"><td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/category[. = current()]"/></td></xsl:for-each>` or with a similar apply-templates.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your reply! <xsl:for-each-group select="//entry" group-by="group"><tr>...</tr></xsl:for-each-group> could work fine, if I would have all the groups covered by entries. There can be some empty groups, without any entry.

Comment: I just tried to fiddle that together at http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKP, at least for the posted sample it seems the approach works. But you can of course also process `groups/group` to create the `tr` rows in the table body and use a key to access the corresponding `entry` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments you might want to use keys to cross-reference from your given groups:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="group-title" match="groups/group/title" use="../@id"/>

<xsl:key name="entry-group" match="entries/entry" use="group"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Groups</th>
              <xsl:for-each select="categories/category">
                  <th>
                      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                  </th>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:variable name="categories" select="categories/category"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="groups/group">
                <tr>
                    <td group-id="{@id}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                    </td>
                    <xsl:variable name="group-id" select="@id"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$categories">
                        <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('entry-group', $group-id)"/>
                        <td group-id="{$group-id}" category-id="{@id}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$group[category = current()/@id]/title"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>                 
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKP/1